# How can I have a custom module checked for deprecated functions?

Tags: 8

I created a custom module in Drupal 8 for a specific purpose.

How can I find out if it contains any deprecated functions?

Comment: Some IDEs can point out when using deprecated class or function e.g. Phpstorm. Also, you can check this repository https://github.com/mglaman/drupal-check

Comment: This question might be a bit off topic since it depends on which IDE you are using, or if you are using any IDE. If you don't use any smart IDE's you can search manually through your project, [here's](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/deprecated/8.7.x) a list of all deprecated functions in Drupal 8.7. If you are using PHPStorm there is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134303/phpstorm-find-all-deprecated-usages-in-the-project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read Dries Buytaert's blog post on [How to prepare for Drupal 9](https://dri.es/how-to-prepare-for-drupal-9)

#### `drupal-check`

> If you work on a Drupal site as a developer, run `drupal-check`. Matt
>   Glaman (Centarro) developed a static PHP analysis tool called
>   `drupal-check`, which you can run against your codebase to check for
>   deprecated code. I recommend running `drupal-check` in an automated
>   fashion as part of your development workflow.

Link: https://github.com/mglaman/drupal-check

#### Upgrade Status

> If you are a site owner, install the Upgrade Status module. This
>   module was built by Acquia. The module provides a graphical user
>   interface on top of `drupal-check`. The goal is to provide an
>   easy-to-use readiness assessment for your site's migration to Drupal
>   9.

Link: https://drupal.org/project/upgrade_status

---

Maybe also learn the background info of `drupal-check` reading Matt Glaman's blog post about [Testing your Drupal code base for deprecated code usage with PHPStan](https://glamanate.com/blog/testing-your-drupal-code-base-deprecated-code-usage-phpstan).